# uWSGI autostart with systemd

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-15.04

So I was trying to get uWSGI and nginx working together and wanted to set the following command line to automatically execute and start my uWSGI background service:

```
uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --uid uwsgi --gid nginx --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --chmod-socket --stats :1717 --no-site --vhost --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

When using systemd I thought the only thing I'd need to do was using `ExecStart=` and starting that command. But since systemd needs absolute paths I take a look in the default uWSGI start script and saw that `/usr/bin/uwsgi` or `usr/sbin/uwsgi` would be the default start path.

So the final exec command for me looks something like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --uid uwsgi --gid nginx --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --chmod-socket --stats :1717 --no-site --vhost --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

The Problem: When running this it's unable to find the option `--no-site` for running everything in a virtualenv.
When starting this with `uwsgi` in the command line it's not a problem. 
But even when starting `/usr/bin/uwsgi` directly from the command line I get this error.

So to me it looks like the `uwsgi`command isn't just running `/usr/bin/uwsgi` directly. But I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I used `whereis uwsgi` to look through every folder that has a uwsgi instance in it again and found out that the default uwsgi application seems to be in `/usr/local/uwsgi`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your uwsgi config in a separate file?

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /path/to/your/app/uwsgi.ini
```

You can read more on uwsgi ini configs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/)